# How to have Django view with variable amount of forms?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

Before I jump into this, I want to know if there is one best way to do this. Let's start from the beginning. I have 3 models, Recipe, Ingredient, and Step. Their models are set up like this:

```py
class Recipe(models.Model):
    prep_time_choices=[
        ('short', 'Short (>20m)'),
        ('medium', 'Medium (20m-1h'),
        ('long', 'Long (<1h)')
    ]
    difficulty_choices=[
        ('easy', 'Easy'),
        ('medium', 'Medium'),
        ('hard', 'Hard')
    ]
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text='Enter the name of this recipe')
    description=models.TextField(max_length=75, help_text='Describe your recipe')
    date=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    prep_time=models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=prep_time_choices, default='short')
    difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=difficulty_choices, default='easy')
    servings=models.IntegerField()
    author= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
        return self.prep_time
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('recipe-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    recipe=models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['ingredient']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ingredient

class Step(models.Model):
    recipe=models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    step=models.TextField(max_length=750)
    number = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['number']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.recipe.name}: {self.number}'
```

What I want to do is create a create view, that allows a user to create 1 Recipe, variable amount of ingredients and, variable amount of steps, presumably adding inputs using JavaScript. Ideally, it'd be as simple as just making a class based view and making it inherit from Django's builtin CreateView, however, as far as I know, that only works for one model. Can anyone help?

Comment: I know this is not the best way to do it, but you can overwrite the post function in your create view and generate a new object for the other model with the cleaned data.

Comment: @pzvkn I'm not sure I follow, what I want to do is have the view have one of each form by default, and then a button allowing the user to add an extra form should they need it (ie, if they have multiple ingredients, they press the button, and another form for ingredients pops up)

Comment: You could use javascript to add New input fields. They won't be django form fields so you need to capture the values when the post request is made and then process It.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views